# Keeping 2 x Versions of Xcode on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra

I was rooting around for the answer on StackOverflow to the question above, as I had recently updated to Mac Sierra and by doing so Xcode 7 updated to 8 automatically. I couldn't find the answer to what I wanted, so I decided to share my findings.

Of course I'm not quite ready to invest the time just yet in Swift 3.0 so I wanted to know how to keep two instances of Xcode on my machine for the time being.

Therefore below is how I went about doing this...

Comment: There are already [plenty of existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Xcode+install+two+versions) on this topic. No need for another.

Comment: Really? I didn't come across any when I searched for this exact solution

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and **find Xcode 7.3.1** or equivalent version of what you want to maintain on your machine.
2. Download the file and **double click on it to open the installer**
3. **DON'T** drag it across to Applications just yet
4. Instead, open a Finder Window and **drag it to Desktop/Downloads**, to install it there
5. **Control-click on the Xcode file to "Get Info"**
6. Under Name & Extension, in the text field, change this from Xcode.app to **Xcode7.app** (or equivalent naming convention)
7. **Drag this renamed file into Applications**
8. **Restart Mac**
9. **Open Xcode7** (or new & renamed application)
10. Voila! 2 x instances of Xcode on your Mac (Xcode proper & Xcode7)

I gather you should never open both apps at the same time. However here is a solution that really does help you if you are still currently developing in two apps or environments on different versions of Swift. Hope this helps.